# How to set 'Target Hardware' in Simulink Embedded Coder from a script?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a Simulink project with a lot of sub-projects. I have different environments for which I need to generate code from Simulink. So I am trying to set the Target Hardware from a MATLAB script. I can change other settings just fine, but I don't know how the name of the Target Hardware parameter so I can use set_param(). I have searched for it, but can't seem to find it and it appears that there isn't one.

```
models = {'Model1','Model2','Model2'};

for i=1:length(models)
    open(char(models(i)));
    set_param(char(models(i)),'TargetLang','C++');
    set_param(char(models(i)),'CodeInterfacePackaging','Nonreusable function')
    set_param(char(models(i)),'MaxIdLength','63')

    set_param(char(models(i)),'ZeroExternalMemoryAtStartup','off');
    set_param(char(models(i)),'Toolchain','Linaro Toolchain v4.8');
    save_system(char(models(i)));
end
```

Does anyone know how to set the Target Hardware from a MATLAB script? It doesn't have to be set_param.

**EDIT**

I am using MATLAB 2014a and a screen shot is below.

[image]

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of which param you are referring to? Also which MATLAB version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Is [`TargetHWDeviceType`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gui/hardware-implementation-pane.html#bq_ojmf-1) what you are after? This can be set with `set_param`. It seems to apply to both Device Vendor and Device Type.

**EDIT**

The correct setting to use is [`ProdHWDeviceType`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gui/hardware-implementation-pane.html#bq8t7za-5). For example, to set it to an MPC55xx from Freescale, you need to do:

```
set_param(bdroot,'ProdHWDeviceType','Freescale->MPC55xx')
```

Comment: I looked into that one, but that doesn't seem to be it. If I manually change Target Hardware from the GUI the TargetHWDeviceType value doesn't change. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in my question. I have also looked at ProdHWDeviceType, and that wasn't it either.

Comment: `ProdHWDeviceType' is the correct setting to use. I will update my answer.