# How to get parameter name of "Target hardware"-Field in "Run on target hardware" in Matlab Simulink?

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi, hardware, simulink

I have seen that something similar (yet not exactly the same) has already been asked, yet not for the same field, nor even the same menu.

I am using Matlab Simulink R2014a and looking to set the value of a parameter in the following way:

```
RoHComponent = myConfigSet.getComponent('Run on Hardware');
set_param(RoHComponent, 'TargetHardware', 'Raspberry Pi');
```

However, the concerned field does not tell its name in the help menu, but I need to set it by command line. Could someone tell me its name? I have tried 'TargetHardware' and similar things, but I just can't find it, and "What's this?" does not tell the parameter name.

Have a nice day,

PS: I'd love to insert a screenshot, but as I am some newbie, I can't yet add one as my reputation is too low so I can't show it to you directly. The concerned menu is under: *Configuration> Run on Target Hardware > Target Hardware selection > Target Hardware:*

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588112/how-to-set-target-hardware-in-simulink-embedded-coder-from-a-script/

Comment: This is the question I saw, yet the display is unsettlingly different, and the told parameter does not seem to be the same. The "Target Hardware" this person is referencing to is in "Code generation", not in "Run on Target Hardware". The Matworks Documentation is, for the given parameter, not listing the Raspberry Pi in the possible hardwares - yet it is supported by Matlab and Simulink, as I have the support packages installed.

Comment: OK. I think you can right-click on the property of interest and a drop-down menu should appear with various options. One of those (can't remember which one) should give you the command line equivalent.

Comment: That's the point: what you are talking about is the "What's this?"-dialog, which opens a small doc-window, which gives in most cases the parameter name - yet annoyingly not in this one.
There is indeed a  doc-window that's opening, but the parameter isn't specified anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooo, this turns out to become some sort of a tradition: I ask a seemingly too specific question, and end up answering it myself. ^^;

```
MyModel = load_system('mymodel');

% list configuration sets
CSNames = getConfigSets(MyModel);
ConfSet = getConfigSet(MyModel, CSNames{1});

% get the hardware component
RTSC = ConfSet.getComponent('Run on Hardware');

% have fun with it
RTSC.getProp('TargetExtensionPlatform')
RTSC.setProp('TargetExtensionPlatform', 'None')
RTSC.setProp('TargetExtensionPlatform', 'Raspberry Pi')
```

Or in the short version:

```
ConfSet .getProp('TargetExtensionPlatform')
ConfSet .setProp('TargetExtensionPlatform', 'None')
ConfSet .setProp('TargetExtensionPlatform', 'Raspberry Pi')
```

Yet the longer version allows an insight of how I found it.

Of course, there is a bunch of checks to be done to ensure that the component exists, and that the property is properly set/read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `getProp()` an a `ConfigSet` object to get a list of available properties. This is how I found out that I can use the following call to determine if my model configuration settings support variable-size signals:

```
>> confSet.getProp('SupportVariableSizeSignals')

ans =

on
```

It seems that you can then use both `setProp` and `set_param` to set the new value.

I haven't tested it, but it seems that you cann call `getProp` on components/subcomponents as well. However, the properties seem to be transparent to the "parent" ConfigSet object.

**TL;DR:** `getProp()` helps to identify properties whose name you don't know, but can guess from the list of properties.